# Connecting records [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Table"

```
id_document , merge , merge_order ,name
```

records with same merge , need to by under
merge_order is specific order(in one merge)

Etc.

```
ID123456 , 400 , 1 , Coral
ID654321 , 200 , 2 , Deril
ID654322 , 400 , 2 , Rick
ID654323 , 200 , 1 , Maggie
```

Output in select will be, for example:

```
ID654323 , 200 , 1 , Maggie
ID654321 , 200 , 2 , Deril
ID123456 , 400 , 1 , Coral
ID654322 , 400 , 2 , Rick
```

Here is my select

```
SELECT
   MERGE_ORDER,ID_DOCUMENT,NAME,MERGE 
FROM(select * from Table order by name)-trying to order table before main select  
WHERE MERGE IS NOT NULL                                           
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR MERGE = MERGE 
order SIBLINGS by MERGE_ORDER,NAME)
```

The select works, but now I need to order the result by name, but save records connection (merge).

I need to order rows where `merge_order = 1`. But under ordered rows, put second record with same merge, and where `merge_order = 2`.

```
ID654323 , 200 , 1 , Maggie
ID123456 , 400 , 1 , Coral
```

Comment: Are you sure that this question relates to mysql and not to oracle or some other rdbms product? I'm not aware of connect by clause being used in mysql.

Comment: just put order by 2,3 or column names

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a simple self join:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.merge=t2.merge  --self join
where t2.merge_order=1   --relate the 1st of each merge to each record in the merge
order by t2.name ASC, t1.merge_order ASC   --the name in t2 will be the name from the 1st record, see where clause
```

You may be able to do it with connect by as well, however, you have not updated your product tags and mysql does not have connect by clause. So, I have not considered connect by clause as valid solution.